# Is there anyway to get Pix to move without moving Lulu or using an ability?

Tags: league-of-legends

"Pix, Faerie Companion" also known as Lulu's passive is a small fairy (or faerie?) that fires along side with you, [and a few other things](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lulu/Ability_Details). Is there anyway for me to make it move to a certain position without moving/rotating Lulu or using an ability (ie protect/shield)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pix can only be attached to champions, either enemy or ally. Unlike Orianna's Ball, Pix cannot move to specific locations in the manner that you suggest.

Comment: This answer is correct. Please don't forget to mark it as completed. Green check mark. Thanks. 

PS: just and addition. When he says attached to champion, that means when lulu puts the shield on an ally. Just to make sure you understand. Peace out.